# How to add user input when starting a service in systemd

Tags: linux, unix, systemd, systemctl

I have a service configured in `systemd` that runs a binary file and it runs constantly. The problem is that after running this binary file, you have to confirm Terms&Conditions by typing `y` in the terminal and validating it by click `Enter`. I cannot run this file through this, because the `systemctl` status appears to me as `failed`, because of lack of validation. Does anyone know how I can run this service and automatically accept Terms in terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in such a way:
I created `.sh` file in `usr/bin` with this content:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
yes | /home/marek/webcash/webminer
```

Then I created config file in `systemd` with `ExecStart: /path/to/file.sh`

and now it works - `systemd` is running correctly, the logs are logging, the answer "yes" was typed only once in binary file when the user prompt appeared.